# Scrape data from API that returns 500 in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm stuck here for hours now. I'm trying scrape data from [this](https://scholenopdekaart.nl/zoeken/middelbare-scholen?zoektermen=rotterdam&weergave=Lijst) link.

Primary aim is to get the school names and their email IDs. In order to do that, I need to get the list of schools first which here is not loading because of the API

The data loads from an API whose link is [this](https://scholenopdekaart.nl/api/v1/search/).
The request method is POST and upon sending a POST request, returns 500.

Proof of work:

```
def data_fetch("https://scholenopdekaart.nl/api/v1/search/"):
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'referer': 'https://scholenopdekaart.nl/zoeken/middelbare-scholen/?zoektermen=rotterdam&weergave=Lijst',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    print(response)  # <Response [500]>
```

I was able to scrape data from the other links that had GET request while POST request returns nothing. Am I missing anything right here? I even tried to put all these in the headers and still got 500.

```
headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'dnt': '1',
        'origin': 'https://scholenopdekaart.nl',
        'referer': 'https://scholenopdekaart.nl/zoeken/middelbare-scholen/?zoektermen=rotterdam&weergave=Lijst',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Brave";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-gpc': '1'
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to scrape?

Comment: Primary aim is to get the school names and their email IDs. In order to do that, I need to get the list of schools first which here is not loading because of the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Google Chromes Network tab [to copy the request CURL command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEYI0.png). Then using [postman](/questions/tagged/postman), you can import that curl command, and generate Python Request code with all the data.

Since the response is pure JSON, no need for bs4

Consider the following example:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://scholenopdekaart.nl/api/v1/search/"

payload = json.dumps({
  "zoekterm": "rotterdam",
  "sectorKeuze": 1,
  "weergave": "Lijst"
})
headers = {
  'authority': 'scholenopdekaart.nl',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'origin': 'https://scholenopdekaart.nl',
  'pragma': 'no-cache'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

data = json.loads(response.text)

for school in data['scholen']:
    print(f"{school['bisId']} \t\t {school['naam']}")
```

This will output:

```
25592        VSO Op Zuid
25938        Op Noord
569          Accent Praktijkonderwijs Centrum
572          Accent PRO Delfshaven
574          Marnix Gymnasium
578          Portus Zuidermavo-havo
579          Portus Juliana
580          CSG Calvijn vestiging Meerpaal
582          CBSplus, school voor havo en mavo
588          Melanchthon Schiebroek
589          Melanchthon Wilgenplaslaan
4452         Melanchthon Mavo Schiebroek
594          Melanchthon Kralingen
604          Comenius Dalton Rotterdam
26152        Zuider Gymnasium
... and some more ...
```

Comment: Is postman opensource? I use Insomnia for such stuff. When I copy pasted the curl command, it gave me `https://scholenopdekaart.nl/api/v1/search` this url. Upon sending the request, got 404. The resultant code gave me an empty output. I believe I missed the data part as I had no idea how to add that. Learnt! So, since we're using POST request where we send the data as input, we're not adding a `referer`. Am I right?

Comment: Don't think [postman](https://www.postman.com/) is open-source, it's free tho. It's just an easy way of converting it to Python request. [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header does not matter if it's GET or POST. Looks like the webserver on scholenOpDeKaart.nl does not check it, so no need to pass it. IT was there because Chrome send it, but it's not needed in this case. Hope I've answered your question(s)! Success ;)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [@0stone0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74111162/5625547) this works even with less code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas

json_data = {
    'zoekterm': 'rotterdam',
    'sectorKeuze': 1,
    'weergave': 'Lijst',
}

response = requests.post('https://scholenopdekaart.nl/api/v1/search/', 
                          json=json_data)

data = json.loads(response.content)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["scholen"])
df[["bisId", "naam"]].head()
```

Output:

```
    bisId   naam
0   25592   VSO Op Zuid
1   25938   Op Noord
2   569     Accent Praktijkonderwijs Centrum
3   572     Accent PRO Delfshaven
4   574     Marnix Gymnasium
```

Comment: What does your answer add? You could have left a comment saying; 'you can remove some headers'. Also why the panda? Maybe add an import, or suggest why you've used it. Your code is not runnable now...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My addition to your answer adds simplification. And usually I find it more versatile to create a dataframe for easier data handling (pandas import is added now). But again – I value your opinion and appreciate your comment.

Comment: This is actually good. I just finished this work and looking / trying your code. So, we can actually directly feed the data as json to get the content. But I wanna know how's this possible without actually adding any headers. I assume the website doesn't check for it if I'm not wrong here.

Comment: @theycallmepix Thx! And you're right. This seems to be the case – no header needed. And if I may add to your discussion regarding postman: I use [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) which is a free webservice, that I find quick and easy to use.

Comment: That's great! I'm getting `server not found` upon clicking the link. May be that's because I use VPN. Many thanks!